# Any upgrade to El Capitan causes loop

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have just inherited a late 2015 27” retina iMac.
This was wiped for me, but left to me to reinstall the OS.
I found an excellent thread on here which helped me get past an issue during reinstall of El Capitan by resetting the date.
However, I am now unable to upgrade to any later versions of OSX. I have tried Catalina, Mojave and Monterey but all just get stuck in a processing loop.

Any suggestions on whether I need to ‘trick’ the OS, as I had to with the date for the El Capitan reinstall?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you run First Aid on the drive to see if there are any errors that could be impeding the install?

Comment: See - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400 - the newer installers listed there *might* no longer need it, but High Sierra was always the stepping stone to higher OSes. [They don't need the date fix trick any more.]

Comment: Does internet recovery work?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Had tried all. Bizarrely I just tried a simple install upgrade through the App Store again after a clean El Capitan install via usb. Left it over night and by morning it had managed the process. All seems fine, but every 10-15 minutes it kernel panics and restarts. Frustrating.